# Visual Studio add-in for performance benchmarking

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, benchmarking

I'd like to measure the performance of some code blocks in my c# winforms application. In particular I want to measure performance regression/improvement after some restructuring of the code.

So long I've seen the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. However, I want to avoid writing measuring code into my classes, I would rather prefer to separate measuring from actual code.

As for debugging, you can set breakpoints on several code lines and "jump" from one to the next by "Continue Execution", I imagine something similar for measuring: Mark to lines of code and make Visual Studio display the time elapsing from one to the next.

Is there any **free** feature/add-in in that direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try [NProf](http://code.google.com/p/nprof/) it's not an addin but it's free. Also [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) has an in built [profiler](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/siegfried_pammer/archive/2009/04/04/introducing-a-new-tool-in-sharpdevelop-the-profiler.aspx).

Comment: PS: I know an addin will go a long way in streamlining the development  process but writing VS addins is tedious and addins often break between VS versions so finding good addins is difficult.

Comment: Thanks SDX2000. You maybe right with the VS addin issues. Still I would be interested if there are any.